# maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a fairly simple Maven project:

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>    
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However, I get the following error in m2eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e. pom.xml  /jasperreports-test line 60 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Why do I care if m2eclipse doesn't "support" this task? Maven does, and that's all I really care about. How can I get this error in my project to go away?

Comment: These days m2e provides a quickfix to add the appropriate configuration to your pom.xml to make m2e ignore the unsupported goal.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, what is the quick fix ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana In Eclipse a "quick fix" means: put the cursor on the problem; press Ctrl-1; Choose Quick Fix.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue. You can instruct m2e to ignore this.

**Option 1: pom.xml**

Add the following inside your `<build/>` tag:

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    <!-- Ignore/Execute plugin execution -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                    <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                    <pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <action>
                            <ignore />
                        </action>
                    </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins></pluginManagement>
```

You will need to do Maven... -> Update Project Configuration on your project after this.

Read more: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#m2e_maven_plugin_coverage_status

**Option 2: Global Eclipse Override**

To avoid changing your POM files, the ignore override can be applied to the whole workspace via Eclipse settings.

Save this file somewhere on the disk: https://gist.github.com/maksimov/8906462

In `Eclipse/Preferences/Maven/Lifecycle Mappings` browse to this file and click OK:

[image: Eclipse Settings]

Comment: What if copy-dependencies is a vital step in building your WAR file? I am working with monstrosity the call m2Eclipse and even if changing the action to execute, the vital files are not copied to the target folder...

Comment: For auto-generated ignore settings, @PhoneTech, m2e adds the comment *"This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself."* Not sure what that means though, as you're saying things don't get copied for you.

Comment: Yes, it helped... but that's an awful lot of code to just get rid of a warning :P

Comment: This still gives me a warning, but the error is gone.

Answer (score 58):

This is a problem of M2E for Eclipse [M2E plugin execution not covered](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered).

To solve this problem, all you got to do is to map the lifecycle it doesn't recognize and instruct M2E to execute it.

You should add this after your `plugins`, inside the `build`. This will remove the error and  make M2E recognize the goal `copy-depencies` of `maven-dependency-plugin` and make the POM work as expected, copying dependencies to folder every time Eclipse build it. If you just want to ignore the error, then you change `<execute />` for `<ignore />`. No need for enclosing your `maven-dependency-plugin` into `pluginManagement`, as suggested before.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute />
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: This solves it indeed. And I was being stupid, thinking when people were talking about moving `<plugins>` into `<pluginManagement>` one should actually move the `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>` in there. But it's about the `<groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId> <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>` that needs to be enclosed in `<pluginManagement>`. When using Quick Fix in Eclipse, the same is added *above* the regular `<plugins>`, and it seems that location works fine too. Key is then to change `<ignore>` into `<execute>`. Nice.

Comment: Found I needed <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental> within execute as recommended on the link you provided. Thanks for the answer set me on the right path.

Comment: There is no need to add this AFTER your `plugins` inside the `build`, you can add this before.

Answer (score 37):

If copy-dependencies, unpack, pack, etc., are important for your project you shouldn't ignore it. You have to enclose your `<plugins>` in `<pluginManagement>` tested with Eclipse Indigo SR1, maven 2.2.1

Comment: I'm a bit lost... Does that mean using the code above but with `<execute />` instead of `<ignore />`? Thanks!

Comment: Care to explain a bit more? Just putting a `<plugin>` into `<pluginManagement>` but still referencing it to do its job, still gives me the same warning.

Comment: @CaioToOn, maybe you know some more...? After adding it to `<pluginManagement>` I still need to add a "regular" 2 line `<build><plugins><plugin>...` as well, referencing the one as configured in `<pluginManagement>`, right? (Still seeing Juno complain about the same thing, when in `<pluginManagement>`.)

Comment: @Arjan you should enclose your `plugins` tag with `pluginManagement`. But take a look at the answer I gave below, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12109018/179138 . The suggested one ignores the execution, but don't execute the plugin on Eclipse.

Answer (score 17):

To make it work, instead of ignoring it, you can install the m2e connector for the maven-dependency-plugin:
https://github.com/ianbrandt/m2e-maven-dependency-plugin

Here is how you would do it in Eclipse:

1. go to Window/Preferences/Maven/Discovery/
2. enter Catalog URL: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.4.xml
3. click Open Catalog
4. choose the m2e-maven-dependency-plugin
5. enjoy

Comment: +1 for the RIGHT answer. Just remember make a small edit to the `pom.xml` file after installing the plugin, otherwise the error might not go away.

Comment: In Eclipse Luna the Catalog URL is http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.5.xml

Comment: I tried this but the Catalog URL fields is not editable! Mine is set to : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory.xml (i.e. without the -1.4) at the end. Any ideas, how/where one could adjust that?

Answer (score 8):

Despite answer from CaioToOn above, I still had problems getting this to work initially.

After multiple attempts, finally got it working.
Am pasting my final version here - hoping it will benefit somebody else.

```
    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <!--
            Copy all Maven Dependencies (-MD) into libMD/ folder to use in classpath via shellscript
             --> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libMD</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--  
        Above maven-dependepcy-plugin gives a validation error in m2e. 
        To fix that, add the plugin management step below. Per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12109018
        -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you please provide with the goal to execute in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to load Hadoop project in eclipse. I tried the solutions above, and I believe it might have worked in Eclipse Kepler... not even sure anymore (tried too many things).

With all the problems I was having, I decided to move on to Eclipse Luna, and the solutions above did not work for me.

There was another post that recommended changing the ... tag to package. I started doing that, and it would "clear" the errors... However, I start to think that the changes would bite me later - I am not an expert on Maven.

Fortunately, I found out how to remove all the errors. Go to Window->Preferences->Maven-> Error/Warnings and change "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle..." option to "Ignore". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but I struggled today with this problem also and I used template from this page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
                  <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
                  <version>[ version ]</version>
                  <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                  <classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
                  <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <!-- other configurations here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

and everything works fine under `m2e` 1.3.1.

When I tried to use

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>    
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also got `m2e` error.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the purpose of this entry : m2e now requires _connectors_ to map plugins executions in Eclipse build lifecycle.
<br/>
Even at the time of my comment writing, m2e only supports a few such connectors : you have to use the `lifecycle-mapping` Maven plugin to instruct m2e how to deal with an unsupported plugin (here the `maven-dependency-plugin`)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to navigate to problems tab, right click on error, click apply quick fix. The should generate the ignore xml code and apply it .pom file for you.