# Error on importing mahout using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mahout, pom.xml

I am getting the below message in eclipse

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer 
artifact org.apache:apache:pom:9 from/to central 
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): connection timed out and 'parent.relativePath' 
points at wrong local POM
```

My pom.xml file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
  <artifactId>mahout</artifactId>
  <version>0.5</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>9</version>
  </parent>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Apache Mahout</name>
  <url>http://mahout.apache.org</url>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <organization>
    <name>The Apache Software Foundation</name>
    <url>http://www.apache.org/</url>
  </organization>
  <mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
      <name>User list</name>
      <subscribe>user-subscribe@mahout.apache.org</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>user-unsubscribe@mahout.apache.org</unsubscribe>
      <post>user@mahout.apache.org</post>
      <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/</archive>
      <otherArchives>
        <otherArchive>http://mahout.apache.org/mail/user/</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://mahout.markmail.org/</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://www.nabble.com/Mahout-User-List-f32042.html</otherArchive>
      </otherArchives>
    </mailingList>
    <mailingList>
      <name>Developers List</name>
      <subscribe>dev-subscribe@mahout.apache.org</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>dev-unsubscribe@mahout.apache.org</unsubscribe>
      <post>mahout-dev@mahout.apache.org</post>
      <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-dev/</archive>
      <otherArchives>
        <otherArchive>http://mahout.apache.org/mail/dev/</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://mahout.markmail.org/</otherArchive>
        <otherArchive>http://www.nabble.com/Mahout-Developer-List-f32041.html</otherArchive>
      </otherArchives>
    </mailingList>
    <mailingList>
      <name>Commit notifications</name>
      <subscribe>commits-subscribe@mahout.apache.org</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>commits-unsubscribe@mahout.apache.org</unsubscribe>
      <archive>http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-commits/</archive>
      <otherArchives>
        <otherArchive>http://mahout.apache.org/mail/commits/</otherArchive>
      </otherArchives>
    </mailingList>
  </mailingLists>
  <properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <maven.clover.multiproject>true</maven.clover.multiproject>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>Jira</system>
    <url>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <!-- our modules -->

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-utils</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-buildtools</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- sibling projects -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- 3rd party  -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-benchmark</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.kosmosfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>kfs</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>xmlenc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlenc</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
            <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons.maths</groupId>
        <artifactId>uncommons-maths</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons.watchmaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>watchmaker-framework</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons.watchmaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>watchmaker-swing</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>r03</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-mahout</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
        <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1</version>
      </dependency>


    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${eclipse.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            <buildcommands>
              <java.lang.String>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</java.lang.String>
              <java.lang.String>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleBuilder</java.lang.String>
              <java.lang.String>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdBuilder</java.lang.String>
            </buildcommands>
            <projectnatures>
              <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
              <nature>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleNature</nature>
              <nature>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdNature</nature>
            </projectnatures>
            <additionalConfig>
              <file>
                <name>.checkstyle</name>
                <location>/mahout-eclipse-checkstyle</location>
              </file>
              <file>
                <name>.pmd</name>
                <location>/mahout-eclipse-pmd</location>
              </file>
              <file>
                <name>.ruleset</name>
                <location>/mahout-pmd-ruleset.xml</location>
              </file>
            </additionalConfig>
          </configuration>
          <!-- the 'location' elements above refer to classpath -->
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
              <artifactId>mahout-eclipse-support</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
            <releaseProfiles>release,mahout_release</releaseProfiles>
            <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>
            <goals>deploy</goals>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
              <artifactId>mahout-buildtools</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
              <artifactId>mahout-buildtools</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <rulesets>
              <!-- classpath -->
              <ruleset>../eclipse/src/main/resources/mahout-pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
            <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
            <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
            <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            <includeTests>true</includeTests>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
          </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            <appendedResourcesDirectory>./src/main/appended-resources</appendedResourcesDirectory>
            <resourceBundles>
              <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.4</resourceBundle>
            </resourceBundles>
            <supplementalModels>
              <supplementalModel>supplemental-models.xml</supplementalModel>
            </supplementalModels>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <forkMode>once</forkMode>
          <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m</argLine>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <resourceBundles>
            <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.4</resourceBundle>
          </resourceBundles>
          <supplementalModels>
            <supplementalModel>supplemental-models.xml</supplementalModel>
          </supplementalModels>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>buildtools</module>
    <module>eclipse</module>
    <module>math</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>taste-web</module>
    <module>examples</module>
    <module>utils</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
  </modules>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>fastinstall</id>
      <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>nochecks</id>
      <properties>
        <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <!-- most of this profile lives in other places, like distribution -->
      <id>release.prepare</id>
      <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <pmd.skip>true</pmd.skip>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>sourcecheck</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <compilerArgument>${compile.flags}</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>set.eclipse.output</id>
      <properties>
        <eclipse.outputDirectory>${basedir}/eclipse-classes</eclipse.outputDirectory>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>setup.eclipse</id>
      <build>
        <defaultGoal>process-test-sources</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>setup.eclipse.project</id>
                <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>eclipse</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.5</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.5</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.5</url>
  </scm>
  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>Website</id>
      <url>scp://people.apache.org/home/isabel/public_html/mahout_site</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <!-- surefire runs unit tests -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- checkstyle -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>${project.build.directory}/../../eclipse/src/main/resources/mahout-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- test coverage plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <generateHistorical>true</generateHistorical>
          <licenseLocation>buildtools/clover.license</licenseLocation>
          <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
          <generateXml>true</generateXml>
          <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- generate java doc -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- code duplication - copy and paste detection -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <rulesets>
            <ruleset>../eclipse/src/main/resources/mahout-pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
          <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
          <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
          <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
          <includeTests>true</includeTests>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
[rest of pom omitted]
```

Can u please help me resolve this issue..

Comment: This looks like the standard Mahout pom.xml here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/mahout/mahout/0.5/mahout-0.5.pom

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with the pom.xml - it looks like the standard Mahout 0.5 one. You need to explain what you are trying to do in Eclipse. In general, to use Maven projects in Eclipse, you need to install the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/). Then in Eclipse select

```
File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Project
```

and select the Mahout project on the filesystem.

I checked out Mahout 0.5

```
svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.5/
```

then imported into Eclipse as I describe above. I did get some errors but different to you e.g.

```
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported 
by m2e. pom.xml /mahout-examples line 54 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping 
Problem
```

this is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706017/maven-dependency-plugin-goals-copy-dependencies-unpack-is-not-supported-b) and can be solved by putting `<pluginManagement>` tags around `<plugins>` in `<build>`. However it is not the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after setting proxy in Maven setting.xml

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse try following steps:

- Right click the project->Maven->Update Project
- Check checkbox "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"
- Click OK.

[image]