# How to copy provided Maven dependencies into a chosen directory?

Tags: maven, plugins, scope, dependencies

How to copy all the provided Maven dependency in a "provided-libs" directory?

I'm looking into [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) and I find that there is a way to copy dependencies. But I want to copy into "provided-libs" only the dependencies whose scope is "provided".

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `includeScope` parameter inside the configuration of the [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                <outputDirectory>provided-libs</outputDirectory>                        
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've just found this solution. I was about to avoid such solution because of the error marker that the goal **copy-dependencies** is not supported by m2e. But here I've had my solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706017/maven-dependency-plugin-goals-copy-dependencies-unpack-is-not-supported-b