# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, maven-toolchains-plugin

I am using m2e to build a java project. I need to use **JAVA VERSION 1.6** . So i am trying to configure toolchains plugin to achieve it. by referring the below link.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

But in eclipse it is throwing the below error.

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain
>   (execution: default, phase: validate) pom.xml /Replenishment  line
>   98    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

I referred the [link](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)  but i did not get a proper clarity. Below is the code snippet used for configuring tool chains plugin.

IN pom.XML

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                      <pluginExecutionFilter>
                          <groupId>
                              org.apache.maven.plugins
                          </groupId>
                          <artifactId>
                              maven-toolchains-plugin
                          </artifactId>
                          <versionRange>
                              [1.1,)
                          </versionRange>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>toolchain</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <action>
                          <ignore></ignore>
                      </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>toolchain</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <toolchains>
            <jdk>
              <version>1.6</version>
              <vendor>sun</vendor>
            </jdk>
          </toolchains>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and my toolchains.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- JDK toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>D:\POC\jdk1.6.0_31</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>

</toolchains>
```

Comment: I tried the below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271106/m2e-copy-dependencies-is-not-supported-by-m2e) in stack over flow itself. But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error got resolved after changing my pom.xml file like below. We need to add the maven life cycle plugin  and then include the metadata information in the .

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                      <version>1.6</version>
                      <vendor>sun</vendor>
                    </jdk>
                  </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
          <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                      <pluginExecutionFilter>
                          <groupId>
                              org.apache.maven.plugins
                          </groupId>
                          <artifactId>
                              maven-toolchains-plugin
                          </artifactId>
                          <versionRange>
                              [1.1,)
                          </versionRange>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>toolchain</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <action>
                          <ignore></ignore>
                      </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Comment: Yup, either that or add the m2e plugin for toolchain - this way is easier  especially in a large scale development

Answer (score 5):

For eclipse users, Go to Window >> Preferences >> Maven .

Select Lifecycle Mapping option from menu. The default mapping file location could be in somewhere in eclipse temp directory, instead copy the file lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml file to some location in eclipse directory or maven directory so that it could be easy to refer.

[image: lifecycle-mapping-metadata]

In lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml file add below configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[0.5,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <ignore />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                    <goal>toolchain</goal>
                </goals>
                <versionRange>[0.0,)</versionRange>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <ignore />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

Just do Maven >> Update Project from project view.
This is the easy way to solve the issue.

Comment: versionRange is no longer a required property. It can be left out, if desired. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347602

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the life cycle plugin separately, it can be solved directly by adding `<pluginmanagement>` tag before the `<plugins>` tag as given below.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          ......................
          ......................
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this approach to work. It seems `lifecycleMappingMetadata` is an invalid element at that location. Maybe expand the example more fully.